# HTML5 range input value is not changing inside Bootstrap popover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am Having html5 range input slider inside bootstrap popver, when i change the slider am getting the same value all the time, i can slide the range slider but i can't get the changed value

When i have the same range slider without `display:none` in its container its working well, so weired to me

HTML:

```
<div id="volume-popover" style="display:none;">
   <input type="range" id="volume-bar" class="volume-bar" step="0.1" value="5" style="display:block;">
</div>

<div class="volume-up">                  
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default volume-btn" data-toggle="popover">Hello</button>
</div>
```

JS :

```
$(function () {
     var volumeBar = $("#volume-bar");
    var popOverSettings_volume = {
        placement: 'bottom',
        container: '.volume-up',
        html: true,
        trigger: "manual",
        selector: '.volume-btn',
        content: function () {
        return $('#volume-popover').html();
    }
    }

    $('.volume-btn').popover(popOverSettings_volume).on("mouseenter", function () {
        var _this = this;
        $(this).popover("show");
        $(this).siblings(".popover").on("mouseleave", function () {
            $(_this).popover('hide');
        });
    }).on("mouseleave", function () {
        var _this = this;
        setTimeout(function () {
            if (!$(".popover:hover").length) {
                $(_this).popover("hide")
            }
        }, 100);
        });

    $('body').delegate(volumeBar, 'change', function () {
          console.log(volumeBar.val());
        });
});
```

Fiddle : [Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5k55jmrL/3/)

Comment: You are cloning html of "volume-popover" id into your popover so it does not get updated value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your cloning of html does not get updated value, you have to get value of the popover. Try updating below code in to your JS:

```
 $('body').delegate(volumeBar, 'change', function(evt) {
   console.log($(".popover .volume-bar").val());
  });
```

Also one more thing, when you clone your html into popover it gets same ID appended into popover which you already given to source div in the beginning. So overall its not good idea to use the same id again.
So I think you can refer this fiddle and if you feel that it suits to your requirement you can use in that way: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5k55jmrL/7/)